# switch isn't recognizing more than 1 character

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I must be tired because this should be simple. I am trying to find the values passed into my program from the command line.

Here's the code:

```
private static bool ParseParms(IEnumerable<string> parms)
{

  try
  {
  foreach (var s in parms)
  {
    if (!s.Contains(":")) continue;
    var split = s.Split(Convert.ToChar(":"));
    if (split.Count() != 2) continue;
    Console.WriteLine("split[0]: " + split[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("split[1]: " + split[1]);
    switch (s[0].ToString())
    {
        // branch
      case "b":
        CustomerInfo.Branch = split[1];
        break;

        // account
      case "a":
        CustomerInfo.AccountNumber = split[1];
        break;

        //name
      case "n":
        CustomerInfo.Name = split[1];
        break;

        //street
      case "str":
        CustomerInfo.Street = split[1];
        break;

        // city
      case "c":
        CustomerInfo.City = split[1];
        break;

        // state
      case "st":
        CustomerInfo.State = split[1];
        break;

        // street
      case "z":
        CustomerInfo.Zip = split[1];
        break;

    }

  }

  Console.WriteLine("=======================");
  Console.WriteLine("name: " + CustomerInfo.Name);
  Console.WriteLine("br: " + CustomerInfo.Branch);
  Console.WriteLine("acctno: " + CustomerInfo.AccountNumber);
  Console.WriteLine("street: " + CustomerInfo.Street);
  Console.WriteLine("city: " + CustomerInfo.City);
  Console.WriteLine("state: " + CustomerInfo.State);
  Console.WriteLine("zip: " + CustomerInfo.Zip);
  Console.WriteLine("=======================");


  if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CustomerInfo.Branch) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CustomerInfo.AccountNumber))
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is what I'm passing in:

"b:01" "a:012345" "n:John Doe" "str:123 Street" "st:AL" "c:Bessemer" "z:35020"

The is the console from the debug:

```
split[0]: b
split[1]: 01
split[0]: a
split[1]: 012345
split[0]: n
split[1]: John Doe
split[0]: str
split[1]: 123 Street
split[0]: st
split[1]: AL
split[0]: c
split[1]: Bessemer
split[0]: z
split[1]: 35020
```

This is the results:

```
=======================
name: John Doe
br: 01
acctno: 012345
street: 
city: Bessemer
state: 
zip: 35020
=======================
```

As you can see, the street and state are blank and I can't figure out why...

Halp!

Comment: you have switch (s[0].ToString()) ... shouldn't that be switch( split[0].ToString()) ?

Comment: geez... I knew it was something stupid... thx Synjin

Comment: yea yeah... I see it now guys thank you! :P  I'm tired and have no excuse.

Comment: This is why you should always give meaningful names to variables :P

Comment: @JohnWillemse you are right of course :) I'll fix em.

Comment: @Syjin give me an answer to upvote. You replied first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem was just a typo. You typed

```
switch (s[0].ToString())
```

instead of

```
switch (split[0].ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `switch (s[0].ToString())` to `switch (split[0])` in your switch statement.

`split[0]` contains the string you want to test against.
`s[0].Tostring()` is the first character of the string only.

Your code is working for some but not all cases as some of your cases are single character strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are getting only the first character of your `string`.

```
switch (s[0].ToString())
```

Base on your code you probably rather want to use `split[0]`, instead of `s[0]`.

```
switch (split[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (split[0].ToString())
```

Not,

```
switch (s[0].ToString())
```

some of the case statements works since `s[0]` returns the first character of the `s` string (like b for "b:01").

Answer (score 1):

When you do `s[0].ToString()` you only take the first character of your string.

`s`is allready of type string, and in fact is a Array of chars. So you take the [0]th element of that array

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
switch (s[0].ToString())
```

To

```
switch (split[0].ToString())
```

Ah well if only I was a few minutes faster ...